# IF function on excel with some cell operations

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Im newbie on excel/spreadsheets and I want to do this:

I have a table with one column that contains some intervals with "Steeping times" like 7-15 days (I can change format).

And I have another column with "Recipe Created" (12/02/2017).

What I want is to check if "Current Date/Local date - Recipe created" is between the interval or if it's less or more.

Example:

Steeping time = 7-15

Current Date 18/07/2017 (spanish format) - Recipe created 10/07/2017 = 8

8 is between Steeping time? Yes.

If it is then paint a cell with yellow, if its less than 7 paint it red and if it is more than 15 paint it green.

Maybe its not an IF function but I would do this with IF on javascript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to explore conditional format rules in google sheets

Comment: see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veb6wuROMfWurV0Cm-PhRZc32-A_0GflKRES_WkcemA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google sheets at least, use Format, Conditional formatting. Set the default to be yellow. Add a rule that if the value is less than 7, red. Add a rule that if the value is greater than 15, green.
You can probably find lots of information on calculating date differences all over stack overflow. The date (only, no time) now is:

```
=date(year(now()),month(now()),day(now()))
```

To parse your date  which was in A2 I did (and there may be easier or more robust ways)
`=left(A2,2)` for the day

```
=mid(A2,4,2)
```

for the month
 and `=right(A2,4)`
 for the year then made a date of those as above. Then I put the difference of the 2 dates in a cell and applied conditional formatting based on its contents.

Comment: Thanks!

So I think I can see what I have to do. Maybe I should look for info about dates because with this method I have the problem that if the month is not the same it will create some conflict I think.

But now I have something to start my search, thanks :)

Comment: to be sure, I might also add a rule that it is yellow if the value is between 7 and 15 (or 6.9 and 15.1 if you want inclusive). If you make things into dates as I sketched, month differences should be handled, because dates are time since some day long ago, and so their differences work with just subtraction and nothing fancy.